# Smallest eigenvalue of a nearest neighbor matrix in $2$ dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Consider a 2D square lattice with $n \times n$ lattice sites. A matrix $M_n$ of size $n^2 \times n^2$ is constructed by setting $M_{ij} = u$ (where $0 \leq u \leq 1$) if sites $i$ and $j$ are nearest neighbors, and all the diagonal elements $M_{ii} = 1$.

For example, with $2 \times 2$ lattice sites, we have
$$M_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & u & u & 0 \\ u & 1 & 0 & u \\ u & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & u & u & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ (i.e. lattice 1 has nearest neighbors 2,3 and lattice 2 has nearest neighbors 1,4 etc...). The smallest eigenvalue of $M_2$ is $\lambda_\text{min}^{(2)} = 1-2u$, for $M_3$ it is $\lambda_\text{min}^{(3)} = 1-2\sqrt{2}u$, for $M_4$ it is $\lambda_\text{min}^{(4)} = 1-(1+\sqrt{5})u$. Numerically I seem to get $\lambda_{\text{min}}^{(N)} \to 1-4u$ as $N \to \infty$, but I am not sure how to prove it.

Using the Gershgorin circle theorem, I am able to get the bound $\lambda_{\text{min}}^{(N)} \geq 1-4u$ so it seems like the matrix here saturates the lower bound. Is there a way to prove this?

Comment: I suspect that in general, $M_n - I$ will be matrix of low rank, which would lead to a slightly quicker way to find the eigenvalues of $M_n$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the pattern. It would be helpful if you could explain the order in which the lattice sites are labeled and/or show us what $M_3$ will look like.

Comment: Usually boundary conditions should be specified. I.e. how does your lattice look at the borders? Is it open (so it's just a square) or for example you close borders on each other such that your lattice lie on a torus? The latter choice is very popular and meaningful in physics. It also allows to easily compute the spectrum of such matrix

Comment: In the periodic boundary condition case the eigenvalues have the form $1+2u(\cos(k_x)+\cos(k_y))$ where $k_{x,y}=2\pi j$, $j=0,1,\ldots,n-1$ (I'm going by memory here)

Comment: For concreteness I have labelled the lattice sites sequentially row-wise (i.e. first row: sites from $1$ to $n$, second row: $n+1$ to $2n$ ...), but the specific convention shouldn't affect the spectrum. I have also used open boundary conditions, but since I am only looking for the limiting behavior, periodic boundary condition should give the same result as well.

Comment: @lcv I am curious about the periodic boundary case. For a 1D lattice I have proved a similar statement using periodic boundaries, in which case $M_n$ is a circulant matrix which simplifies the problem greatly. How did you get the form for the eigenvalues in 2D?

Comment: Discrete Fourier transform diagonalizes the PBC case in any dimension. If you're interested I can provide more details

Comment: @lcv It would be great if you could provide more details! I'm not too knowledgeable in this area so this will help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clear that when $u = 0$, $M_n$ has $1$ as its only eigenvalue. With that in mind, I will consider only the consider only the case where $0<u\leq 1$. $I_k$ denotes the $k\times k$ identity matrix.

Note that the matrix $A_n := \frac 1{u} (M_n - I_{n^2})$ is the adjacency matrix of the [square grid graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph). Because this square grid is the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) of the length-$n$ path with itself, we have
$$
A_n = B_n \otimes I_n + I_n \otimes B_n,
$$
where $B_n$ denotes the adjacency matrix of the path graph on $n$ vertices and $\otimes$ denotes a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). It follows that the eigenvalues of $A_n$ are of the form $\lambda_i + \lambda_j$ for $1 \leq i,j \leq n$, where $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $B_n$. [It is known](https://www.whitman.edu/documents/Academics/Mathematics/Jones.pdf) that the eigenvalues of $B_n$ are given by
$$
\lambda_j = 2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi j}{n+1} \right), \quad j = 1,2,\dots,n.
$$
It follows that the smallest eigenvalue of $B_n$ is given by $\lambda_n = 2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{n+1} \right) = -2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)$. So, the smallest eigenvalue of $A_n$ is $2 \lambda_n = -4\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right).$ So, the smallest eigenvalue of $M_n = I_{n^2} + uA_n$ is given by
$$
\lambda_{\min} = 1 - 4u \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n+1} \right).
$$
The conclusion follows.

---

Proof of the Cartesian product formula:

Suppose that we have graphs $G_1$ over nodes $[m]=\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $G_2$ over nodes $[n] = \{1,\dots,n\}$. Let $A^i$ denote the adjacency matrix of graph $G_i$ (for $i = 1,2$) and let $A$ denote the adjacency matrix of the Cartesian product $G = G_1 \square G_2$. Take the elements of $[m]\times[n]$ in lexicographical order, so that the entry $(e_i^{(m)} \otimes e_j^{(n)})^TA(e_p^{(m)} \otimes e_q^{(n)})$ is equal to $1$ iff the nodes $(i,j)$ and $(p,q)$ are adjacent within the Cartesian product $G$ (where $e_1^{(n)},\dots,e_n^{(n)}$ is the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$).

We assume that $G_1$ and $G_2$ contain no loops, so $i = j$ and $i \sim j$ cannot simultaneously be true.

By the definition of the Cartesian product, we have $(e_i^{(m)} \otimes e_j^{(n)})^TA(e_p^{(m)} \otimes e_q^{(n)}) = 1$ iff $i=p$ and $j \sim q$ ($j$ is adjacent to $q$) or $i \sim p$ and $j = q$. Verify that this is logically equivalent to saying that
$$
(e_i^{(m)} \otimes e_j^{(n)})^TA(e_p^{(m)} \otimes e_q^{(n)}) = \delta_{ip} A^{2}_{j,q} + A^{1}_{i,p} \delta_{jq}.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
(e_i^{(m)} \otimes e_j^{(n)})^T[A^1 \otimes I_m + I_n \otimes A^2](e_p^{(m)} \otimes e_q^{(n)}) = \\
(e_i^{(m)} \otimes e_j^{(n)})^T[A^1 \otimes I_m ](e_p^{(m)} \otimes e_q^{(n)})
+ 
(e_i^{(m)} \otimes e_j^{(n)})^T[I_n \otimes A^2](e_p^{(m)} \otimes e_q^{(n)}) =\\
((e_i^{(m)})^T e_p^{(m)})((e_i^{(n)})^T A_2 e_p^{(n)}) + ((e_i^{(m)})^T A_1 e_p^{(m)})((e_i^{(n)})^T e_p^{(n)}) =\\
\delta_{ip}A^2_{j,q} + A^{1}_{i,p} \delta_{jq}.
$$
So, we indeed have $A = A^1 \otimes I_m + I_n \otimes A^2$.

Comment: Interesting, how can you prove that assertion? Meaning, how can you find that tensor product structure?

Comment: @lcv This is a fairly straightforward consequence of the definition of the Cartesian product of graphs, taking a lexicographical ordering of the product. If you want an authoritative source, the Wikipedia page on the Cartesian product of graphs gives the following: Kaveh, A.; Rahami, H. (2005), "A unified method for eigendecomposition of graph products", Communications in Numerical Methods in Engineering with Biomedical Applications, 21 (7): 377–388, doi:10.1002/cnm.753, MR 2151527.

Comment: @lcv See my latest edit

Comment: Thank you, interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the very clear explanation!

Answer (score 1):

As per request in the comment I will give the answer for the case of periodic boundary condition (PBC). In particular I will compute all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I will also generalize to $d$ dimension (instead of $d=2$ as per the question).

Let us consider a lattice $\Lambda=\left\{ 1,2,\ldots,L_{1}\right\} \times\left\{ 1,2,\ldots,L_{2}\right\} \times\cdots\left\{ 1,2,\ldots,L_{d}\right\} \subset\mathbb{Z}^{d}$. Hence $\Lambda$ is an hypercube in $d$ dimensions. Periodic boundary conditions mean that we identify edges (so for $d=1$ we have a circle, $d=2$ a torus, and in general our lattice lies on a $d$ dimensional torus.

Putting periodic boundary condition on the lattice is the same as
considering functions on $\Lambda$ satisfying $f(x)=f(x+L_{i}e_{i})$
for all $x\in\Lambda$, and $i=1,2,\ldots,d$, where $e_{i}$ is the
unit vector in the '$i$' direction, i.e., $e_{1}=(1,0,0,\ldots,0),\,e_{2}=(0,1,0,\ldots,0),\,e_{d}=(0,0,0,\ldots,1)$.

The matrix we are considering is given by
$$
A_{x,y}=\begin{cases}
1 & \mathrm{if}\,\,x,y\mathrm{\,\,are\,\,n.n.}\\
0 & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
for all $x,y\in\Lambda$, where n.n. indicates nearest neighbor.
Let us write $|x\rangle$ for the vector $(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{d})^{T}$.
The matrix above corresponds to the action of the following operator
$$
A|x\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{d}\left(|x+e_{i}\rangle+|x-e_{i}\rangle\right)
$$
where we always understand that PBC are used for the vectors $|x\rangle$.
We now define the Fourier transform
\begin{align*}
|k\rangle & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_{x\in\Lambda}e^{-ikx}|x\rangle\\
|x\rangle & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_{k\in\Lambda^{*}}e^{ikx}|k\rangle
\end{align*}
where $V=\prod_{i=1}^{d}L_{i}$ and the dual lattice is defined by
\begin{align*}
\Lambda^{*} & =\left\{ 0,\frac{2\pi}{L_{1}},2\frac{2\pi}{L_{1}},\ldots,(L_{1}-1)\frac{2\pi}{L_{1}}\right\} \times\cdots\\
 & \times\left\{ 0,\frac{2\pi}{L_{d}},2\frac{2\pi}{L_{d}},\ldots,(L_{d}-1)\frac{2\pi}{L_{d}}\right\} .
\end{align*}
The dual lattice is such that, for $k\in\Lambda^{*}$, $e^{ik_{i}L_{i}}=1$.
One can check that with the above definition the (discrete) Fourier
transform is a unitary operation.

Now one can evaluate
\begin{align*}
A|k\rangle & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_{x\in\Lambda}e^{-ikx}A|x\rangle\\
 & =\sum_{i=1}^{d}\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_{x\in\Lambda}e^{-ikx}\left(|x+e_{i}\rangle+|x-e_{i}\rangle\right).
\end{align*}
Thanks to the PBC (toroidal) nature of $\Lambda$ we can change variable
in the sum: $y=x+e_{i}$ and $y=x-e_{i}$ and obtain
\begin{align*}
A|k\rangle & =\sum_{i=1}^{d}\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_{y\in\Lambda}\Big(e^{-ik(y-e_{i})}|y\rangle+e^{-ik(y+e_{i})}|y\rangle\Big)\\
 & =\sum_{i=1}^{d}e^{ike_{i}}|k\rangle+e^{-ike_{i}}|k\rangle\\
 & =\sum_{i=1}^{d}\left(e^{ike_{i}}+e^{-ike_{i}}\right)|k\rangle\\
 & =\left[2\sum_{i=1}^{d}\cos(k_{i})\right]|k\rangle
\end{align*}

Which shows that the eigenvalues of $A$ have the form $\lambda_{k}=2\sum_{i=1}^{d}\cos(k_{i})$,
$k_{i}=2\pi n_{i}/L_{i}$, $n_{i}=0,1,\ldots,L_{i}-1$, (and the eigenvectors
are the plane waves $|k\rangle$).

The matrix $M$ in the question corresponds to $d=2$, $L_1 = L_2 =n$ and

$$
M = I - uA
$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix.